# Converting strings in a list to integers python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, int, converters, bubble-sort

I am trying to open a csv file and convert the values from strings to integers so I can sort the list. Currently when I sort the list the results I get are `"[[], ['190'], ['200'], ['250'], ['350'], ['90']]"`. Here is my code.

```
import csv

def bubbleSort(scores):
    for length in range(len(scores)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(length):
            if scores[i]>scores[i+1]:
                temp = scores[i]
                scores[i] = scores[i+1]
                scores[i+1] = temp


with open ("rec_Scores.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    scores = list(r)


bubbleSort(scores)
print(scores)
```

This is probably really easy to fix, but I am still new to python so if anyone could help me solve this problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `scores = list(r)` should be changed to `scores = [[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in row] for row in r]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add scores_int = [int(score) for score in scores] in order to convert the string numbers in your scores list to int numbers. This is what your code should look like:

import csv

```
def bubbleSort(scores):
    for length in range(len(scores)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(length):
        if scores[i]>scores[i+1]:
            temp = scores[i]
            scores[i] = scores[i+1]
            scores[i+1] = temp


with open ("rec_Scores.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
r = csv.reader(csvfile)
scores = list(r)
scores_int = [int(score) for score in scores]

    bubbleSort(scores_int)
    print(scores)
```

Comment: When I add that I get the error message "TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"

Comment: Try scores_int = [int(score[0]) for score in scores]